# Cakephp cms toutorial problem Tag section

Tags: cakephp, content-management-system

i’m having some problem in the tag section:
i’ve created the `_getTagString` method inside the `article.php` entity

but the prop `$this->tags` is empty so the function return empty string.

i’ve copy pasted all the code, but i’m missing something. i’ve also added this line inside `articesTable : $this->belongsToMany(‘Tags’);`

edit:

```
$article = $this->Articles->findBySlug($slug)->firstOrFail();
```

with this line cake is getting my article and all the associated tags? so inside the entity i should have it right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add contain(['Tags']) in because Cakephp 3 not automatically include Associations Table

```
$this->Articles->findBySlug($slug)->contain(['Tags'])->firstOrFail();
```

[Cakephp 3 Guide](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)